# "Unable to find any implementation of the contract" Exception in LightSwitch extension

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm teaching myself Visual Studio LightSwitch by porting [Excel Importer extension](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Excel-Importer-for-Visual-61dd4a90).
I have all the pre-requisites (Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate edition, Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK, Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 Extensibility Toolkit) except that I'm using LightSwitch Beta 2.

While trying to execute this line,

```
IServiceProxy sdkProxy = VsExportProviderService.GetExportedValue<IServiceProxy>();
```

I get the following exception:

> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is
>
> > provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for
> >     more detailed information.
> >
> > 1) Unable to find any implementation of the contract:
> >     'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Sdk.Proxy.IServiceProxy'

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
IServiceProxy sdkProxy = VsExportProviderService.GetExportedValue<IServiceProxy>();
```

[MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (Managed Extensibility Framework) will try to find an implementation of the `IServiceProxy` interface. It seems that it cannot find any implementation.

Does that help you?

Comment: Not really. As far as I can see, the LightSwitch libraries should provide the implementation. So whats going wrong in this case?

Comment: You need to use the RTM version of LightSwitch. The Extensibility Toolkit was only released after LS RTM was released. There's no reason to be using B2 any more, & it's due to expire on October 11 anyway. The trial version of LightSwitch is good for 30 days (extendable to 90 days if you register it).

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve my problem by doing a complete re-install of Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate edition, Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK, Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 Extensibility Toolkit and LightSwitch. 
I tried everything I could think of to avoid this but after finding that the Microsoft samples themselves failed to build with the exact same error, I concluded that some DLL that contained the implementation IServiceProxy was probably out of date or not registered.

I can now build the solution with no issues.